# Kopplung von Adjektiven und Namensbestandteilen

Tags: adjective, compound

In einem [Artikel](https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/gesellschaft/knigge-tipps-in-der-pandemie-wie-kann-ich-hoeflich-reagieren-wenn-mich-jemand-anpoebelt-a-d65d9f0e-c6bc-457d-84c2-bd068948d2fc) besteht eine Interviewte auf einer für mein Verständnis merkwürdigen, **doppelten Kopplung von "Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft" (sic!)**. Ich dachte die Kopplungsregeln vestanden zu haben und würde auch vom Deutschen-Knigge-Gesellschaft-Interview sprechen, aber trotzdem

> Frau Kaiser von der Deutschen Knigge-Gesellschaft gab ein Interview.

formulieren. "Knigge" als Eigenname würde ich an "Gesellschaft" koppeln, aber gilt das auch für das stark adjektivisch verwendete "Deutsche"?

Edit: Mir war nicht bewusst, dass der Artikel hinter einer Bezahlschranke liegt, daher zitiere ich die relevanten Stellen:

> **SPIEGEL:** Frau Kaiser, als ich Ihnen gemailt habe, habe ich aus Versehen »Sehr geehrter **Deutsche Knigge-Gesellschaft**« geschrieben. Wie kommen solche Fehler bei Ihnen an?

> **Kaiser:** Das ist mir gar nicht aufgefallen. Ich habe eher auf **die Bindestriche geachtet. Da gehören zwei rein.** Höflicher wäre es auch gewesen, wenn Sie mich mit Namen angesprochen hätten, aber der erfreuliche Inhalt Ihrer Anfrage ist mir wichtiger.

Und später in einem abgesetzten Kasten:

> Linda Kaiser ist die stellvertretende Vorsitzende der **Deutschen-Knigge-Gesellschaft**.

Comment: Danke für diesen Einblick in die absurde Welt der "zertifizierten Trainer für Business-Etikette". Vielleicht geht es um die Absetzung von der Volksfront von Judäa der Businessetikettetrainer, dem "Deutschen Knigge-Rat"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Der einzige Grund, *Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft* so zu schreiben, ist, dass sie es so möchte.

Zunächst einmal gibt es in den [offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) an mehreren Stellen Pauschalausnahmen für Eigennamen:

- > Für Eigennamen (Vornamen, Familiennamen, geografische Eigennamen und dergleichen) gelten im Allgemeinen amtliche Schreibungen. Diese entsprechen nicht immer den folgenden Regeln.
- > Zusammensetzungen aus Eigennamen und Substantiv zur Benennung von Schulen, Universitäten, Betrieben, Firmen und ähnlichen Institutionen werden so geschrieben, wie sie amtlich festgelegt sind.

Wenn die Deutsche Knigge-Gesellschaft also amtlich als *Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft* eingetragen ist, gebieten einem die Rechtschreibregeln sogar, sie so zu schreiben¹. Das gölte aber genauso, wenn sie sich als *dEuTsChE kπi99e gəsëełłšaft* hätte eintragen lassen.

Andererseits ist Rechtschreibung kein reiner Selbstzweck, sondern dient der besseren Lesbarkeit. Hier muss man dann häufig dazwischen abwägen, ob man seine Leserschaft über von Ahnungslosigkeit oder Werbeüberlegungen getriebene Selbstschreibungen stolpern lassen oder die beschriebene Organisation verprellen möchte. Diverse Stilregeln (und ich) empfehlen hier, die Namen den allgemeinen Rechtschreibregeln für Eigennamen anzupassen, z. B.:

- [Die Richtlinien der Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Namenskonventionen#Organisationen_und_Einrichtungen)
- [The Slot](https://www.theslot.com/webnames.html) (ist zwar auf Englisch, die Argumentation ist aber sprachunabhängig)

Dies betrifft zum einen Außenstehende, aber natürlich auch die Knigge-Gesellschaft selbst, die überlegen muss, ob es mit ihren Werten entspricht, eine Schreibung zu verwenden, die mit den Rechtschreibregeln nur über Ausnahmeregelung vereinbar ist.

Was besagen schließlich die [Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) für Eigennamen? Abgesehen von der oben zitierten Narrenfreiheitsklausel ändert sich für Eigennamen eigentlich nur die Groß- und Kleinschreibung:

> § 60: In mehrteiligen Eigennamen mit nichtsubstantivischen Bestandteilen schreibt man das erste Wort und alle weiteren Wörter außer Artikel, Präpositionen und Konjunktionen groß.
>
> […]
>
> Beispiele: […] *Deutscher Gewerkschaftsbund, […], Deutsche Bank, Österreichischer Raiffeisenverband*

… und die Schreibung von Zusammensetzungen mit Eigennamen als Bestandteil, u. a.:

> § 51: Man kann einen Bindestrich in Zusammensetzungen setzen, die als
> ersten Bestandteil einen Eigennamen haben, der besonders hervor-
> gehoben werden soll, oder wenn der zweite Bestandteil bereits eine
> Zusammensetzung ist.
>
> […]
>
> Beispiele: […] *Kafka-Kolloquium*

Dementsprechend wären korrekt:

> Deutsche Knigge-Gesellschaft
> Deutsche Kniggegesellschaft

---

¹ Ob sie dann auch entsprechend nicht gebeugt wird (»Die Vorsitzende der Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft«), ist eine Grammatikfrage und somit außerhalb der Zuständigkeit der Rechtschreibregeln.

Comment: Der Argumentation kann ich sehr gut folgen, allein frage ich mich, auf was genau sich die angeführten Paragraphen beziehen. Kannst Du das noch hinzufügen?

Comment: @NilsMagnus: Siehe meinen Edit.

Comment: Die Rechtschreibregeln zu erwähnen, wäre eigentlich vollkommen unnötig gewesen - Wenn die Gesellschaft sich gerne mit zwei Bindestrichen schreiben will, dann ist das - wie du richtig sagst - eben so - egal was der RSR sagt.

Comment: @tofro: Wenn das so klar wäre, hätte der Fragesteller die Frage gar nicht erst gestellt und von der Antwort bliebe auch nicht viel übrig. Wie erwähnt, gibt es aber durchaus Leute, die empfehlen, Eigennamen den Regeln anzupassen, und auch Regeln zur Schreibung von Eigennamen in den Rechtschreibregeln. Man kann also schon festhalten, dass die Deutsche Knigge-Gesellschaft sich entschieden hat, ihren Namen entgegen der Rechschreibregeln (minus Narrenfreiheitsausnahme) zu schreiben und was für Argumente dafür und dagegen sprechen, dies mitzumachen.

Comment: Ich hätte es wichtiger gefunden, zu erwähnen, dass die gewählte Kopplung eher problematisch ist, wenn sie (wie hier) Deklinationselemente enthält. Der Vorsitzende muss sich nämlich jetzt entscheiden, ob er der Vorsitzende der "Deutschen-Knigge-Gesellschaft" oder der "Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft" ist (was für mich beides ungefähr gleich falsch aussieht)

Answer (score 1):

Hinweis vorweg: Den verlinkten Artikel kann man ohne Abo nicht lesen, deshalb weiß ich nicht genau, was drin steht und muss das aus Deiner Frage interpolieren.

Nun zur Antwort: Du stolperst hier über die Verwendung eines Eigennamens.

Es handelt sich nicht um eine Knigge-Gesellschaft, die das adjektiv "deutsch" besitzt, sondern um eine Gesellschaft, die sich selbst den Eigennamen [Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft e.V.](http://deutsche-knigge-gesellschaft.de/) gegeben hat.

Insofern handelt es sich im Artikel (vermutlich, siehe oben) um die Nennung genau dieses Eigennamens und nicht um eine Kopplung unabhängiger Wörter.

Jeder kann bei der Vergabe des Namens seiner Gesellschaft frei über Schreibweise, Zusammensetzung, etc. entscheiden, eine grammatikalische Erklärung muss es hierfür nicht geben.

Comment: Interessanterweise verwendet die Gesellschaft selbst das "Deutsche-" adjektivisch, man ist bspw. "Willkommen bei der Deutschen-Knigge-Gesellschaft". Sinnvoll wäre die Kopplung, wenn es um eine "Deutsche Knigge" (im Vgl. bspw. zu einer österreichischen) geht, für die eine Gesellschaft gegründet wurde. Aber auch dann würde man ja "Willkommen bei der Deutsche-Knigge-Gesellschaft" schreiben.

Comment: Ja, Du hast vollkommen recht: Das ist mir beim Check der Website auch aufgefallen...

Comment: So ganz einig sind sich "die Medien" da auch nicht: In unser regionalen Tageszeitung, dem Darmstädter Echo, steht heute ein (anderes) Interview mit dem Vorsitzenden der "Deutschen Knigge-Gesellschaft", also mit nur einem Bindestrich.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Die heutigen Tageszeitungen sind schon länger keine Referenz mehr - selbst die Tagesschau hat inzwischen viele Fehler in Texten.